# What happens on Hoshanah Rabbah?

Tags: yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, hashgacha-pratit, hoshana-rabbah

On Rosh Hashanah the judgment is written.

On Yom Kippur it is sealed.

But we really have until Hoshanah Rabbah to repent.  The Zohar [[Tzav 31b](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1460472/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Tzav-Day-3.htm)] says that's when the judgment is delivered.

Who is delivering it and to whom?  (God to the angels so they can make it happen?)